# Decimal Value to String

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-2.0

Below computation should result to value of 33.3333333 but I'm not getting the right output in the message box when tying to display the value.

Is there any formatting that needs to be done first here?

```
decimal result = (1/3)*100;
MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
```

[image]

Comment: `decimal result = (1m / 3) * 100;`

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are performing your calculation using integers, therefore the result is an `int` and converted to `decimal` on assignment. Since `1/3` is already `0` (in `int` arithmetic) multiplying it by `100` doesn't change anything there.

Use decimals instead:

```
decimal result = (1m / 3m) * 100m;
```

The `m` suffix on a numeric literal makes it a decimal.

Incorporated a comment from [Kay Zed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10946391/decimal-value-to-string#comment14285347_10946412):

> If you are dealing with variables and not literals you can cast:
>
> ```
> decimal result = ((decimal)a / (decimal)b) * 100m;
> ```

Comment: Thanks Joey, will try this one.

Comment: Use `decimal a = 1, b = 3` in that case. Or what Kay Zed proposes below, depending on how your code looks in that part.

Comment: @Joey That would work, but `(1m/3m) * 100m` is a tad more coherent, and being lazy in type defs was what ultimately brought Ariane down. @yonan2236 That would not work, same case as original question (read Joey's splendid answer).

Comment: In that case you should cast: decimal result = ((decimal) a / b) * 100;

Comment: flindeberg: Indeed, I have changed that. I'm probably a little too sure of my types usually (and I know the conversion rules) so I tend to be lazy there as well ;-)

Comment: Agreed with flindeberg. It's good style to know what types you're dealing with anyway. Always use the proper suffixes on literals.

Comment: Although you rely on the same conversion rules with the casting I did with just making a single literal `decimal` ;)